# Can't sign blackberry app..Error preverifying class

Tags: blackberry, sign

I'm getting this strange problem I can't seem to find a soluition of. I have included net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar in my project with the help of the following method:

1. In Eclipse, open the BlackBerry Application Development perspective.
2. Click File > New > BlackBerry Project.
3. In the New BlackBerry Project dialog box, in the Project Name field, type a name for your project.
4. In the JRE section, make sure you select a BlackBerry JRE that is version 5.0 or later, and click Finish.
5. In the Package Explorer view, right-click the project and click Properties.
6. In the Properties dialog box, in the left pane, click Java Build Path.
7. Click the Libraries tab.
8. Click the Add External JARs button.
9. Navigate to the folder where you extracted the BlackBerry Messenger SDK file,. In the BBM SDK folder, doubleclick
   net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar.
10. Click Next.
11. In the properties window, click OK.
12. When you are ready to build your project, on the Project menu, click BlackBerry > Package All.

But this method creates a tempXXXXX folder everytime I sign my app and there appears an Error (X) mark on the project folder. And the console says:

Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\bin\preverify.exe -d C:\Users\ ...
Packaging project MyBBMApp failed (took 1.285 seconds)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your subject says you have problems signing the file. In order to sign the file, make sure you have the three signing files available on your system (RBB, RCR and RRT). In order to sign an app, the files first need to be included:

BlackBerry (located at the top) -> Sign -> Install New Keys

Once the keys are included in your project, sign your app:

Right Click project -> BlackBerry -> Sign with Signation Tool. It will prompt for a password which is what you created when getting your keys.

Once the app is signed, package your project:

Right Click project -> BlackBerry -> Package Project

Make sure your app has no compilation errors in order for the app to package successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no signing problems. The other apps I have made, sign successfully. Also, there are no compilation errors in my project. What I'm talking about is that there comes an error when I sign my app: Error!: Error: preverifier failed: C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\bin\preverify.exe -d C:\Users\ ... Packaging project MyBBMApp failed (took 1.285 seconds)  And this error comes after I include the net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar file in the build path. How can I sign my app without this error and including this .jar file?

Comment: This indicates there are issues including this particular jar file in your app. It might be incompatible. It might not support your jdk version.

Comment: I'm using JRE 7 and BBM SDK v1.3. And just now I have come to know with the help of the following link that The BlackBerry Messenger platform does not support 64-bit Java, or Java 7: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/bbm_ww_download_tools_1987807_11.html What can I do in this case?

Comment: Can you not use older versions of java in your development? Does the project not compile with older java?